# Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' in for loop even though already included

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, for-loop

Below is code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {
        var sliderValue = Int(sender.value)
        println(sliderValue)
    }

    @IBOutlet var sliderValue: UISlider!

    var arr:[Int] = []

    for index in 0...21 {
        arr.append(index)
    }

    println(arr)

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    /*
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = sliderValue.value * arr[indexPath.row]
    }
    */
}
```

It gives me the error on line 3.

[image: Screenshot for error]

**I had to delete some code, stack overflow didn't like that much code. I only deleted the viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very simple fix: you have to add a blank between the `++` operator and the opening bracket:

```
for var i = 0; i < 21; i++ { 
                          ^
```

without that, I think the compiler tries to consider `++{` as an operator.

An alternate way of initializing an array with increasing numbers is:

```
var arr: [Int] = (0..<21).map {$0}
```

**Update**

Code must go inside a method - you cannot execute code at the same level of properties. I suggest initializing that property inline using the alternate method described in my answer, that should work.

If you still want to use inline initialization, but you have more complex code to execute, you can also initialize the property by defining a closure and immediately execute it:

```
var arr:[Int] = {
    var array = [Int]()
    for index in 0...21 {
        array.append(index)
    }
    return array
}()
```

Comment: It still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: @kevini15 Pls double check if you have written it correctly. Pasting your code into a playground and adding that blank works

Comment: Also it's possible that there is another error somewhere else - try commenting the for loop and see if you still have an error

Comment: It works in playground. Even my original code without the space between ++ and { works.

Comment: @kevini15: You probably have that code outside of a method or function.

Comment: I added the whole code into my question. Xcode only detects that one error though

Comment: @kevini15: You have to move the loop into a *method* of the view controller. – I am sure this has been answered before, but it might be difficult to find the duplicate.

Comment: Oh ok.. thank you, it works now. How can I mark your comment as the answer, Martin?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the swift syntax for the for loop:

```
for i in 1..<21 {
 arr.append(i)
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error "Expected declaration"... ? but it works in playground.

Comment: then there should be an error somewhere else in your code, according to the swift reference, it is a valid statement